# jquery plugin(Impromptu)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am wondering, how can i use this plugin in my html?

```
$.prompt("Open your javascript console to see the answer.", {
title: "Are you Ready?",
buttons: { "Yes, I'm Ready": true, "No, Lets Wait": false },
submit: function(e,v,m,f){
    // use e.preventDefault() to prevent closing when needed or return false. 
    // e.preventDefault(); 

    console.log("Value clicked was: "+ v);
}
});
```

that code was from http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/

Comment: Just include that plugins in your code and use as alert box in your page write that code when you want to show alert.

Comment: i already did that but no luck.

Comment: Will you post what you have tried?

Comment: sorry but i dont know how to include the impromptu's js file in jsfiddle

Comment: You can include script files in the left-side panel, under external resources.

Comment: @TigerTropa I edited my answer with css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use that library and it's work.

Include library:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/jquery-impromptu.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```
<link href="http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/jquery-impromptu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

Write script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var multiplePromptsCounter = 1;

function openMultiplePrompts(){

    $.prompt("Do you want to open another?", {
        title: "A Prompt Has Opened: "+ multiplePromptsCounter++,
        buttons: { "Yes, Open Another": true, "No, Close This One": false },
        persistent: false,
        submit: function(e,v,m,f){
            if(v){
                e.preventDefault();
                openMultiplePrompts();
            }
        }
    });
}
 </script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="buttons">
<button class="run" onclick="openMultiplePrompts()" >Run It!</button>
</div>
```

Hope it help you.

Comment: can i use submit button for that?

Comment: I don't know much. But will you try that?